# How does Unobserved Components Model work ? What exactly does it do after decomposing the time series in components?

Tags: time-series, arima, unobserved-components-model

I was working on Unobserved Components Model in R but found that the content in the help section of R is not very elaborate.Maybe it's not completely updated yet. The Nile dataset example online also does not get a lot into how the model works.

I want to know how UCM is different to ARIMA and other time series models. When do we opt for this model over the others ?

Could someone point me towards a source of documentation on this.

Comment: You should spell out what UCM means, please!

Comment: I had the same question and found this paper from Siem Jan Koopman and Marius Ooms: [Forecasting economic time series using unobserved components time series models](https://www2.gwu.edu/~forcpgm/SiemJanKoopman-final-2010UCForecasting.pdf)